# Save Outlook email Information to SQL Server

Tags: c#, outlook, console-application, com-interop, office-automation

I'm trying to save inbound Outlook mail data to sql server however I'm getting in error in System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.' What did I missed

Note: RetrieveMail is exist in mailbox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection; // to use Missing.Value
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace RetrieveEmail
{
    public class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlook.Application oLk = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._NameSpace olNS = oLk.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook._Folders oFolders;
            oFolders = olNS.Folders;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder;
            oFolder = oFolders[1];
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolderIn = oFolder.Folders["RetrieveMail"];

            Outlook.Items oItems = oFolderIn.Items;
            foreach (Outlook.MailItem oMailItem in oFolderIn.Items)
            {
                if (oMailItem.SenderName == "sender_name")
                {

                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=EmailReply;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Emails", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Subject", oMailItem.Subject);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Body", oMailItem.Body);

                    con.Open();
                    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (k != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Record Inserted Succesfully into the Database");

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the folder RetrieveMail exist in the mail box?

Comment: Yes it is exist

Comment: Where is the folder located relative to the other folders, such as the Inbox?

Comment: I created the RetrieveMail folder under Inbox only. Do I need to recreate a folder? Sorry I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method to get the Inbox folder and then try to get the required subfolder instead. For example:

```
Sub DisplaySubfolderOfInboxFolder()
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myFolder = myInbox.Folders(1) 
 
 myFolder.Display 
 
End Sub
```

So, in your code it should look like that:

```
Outlook.Application oLk = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook._NameSpace olNS = oLk.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook._Folders oFolders;
Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder =  olNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);           
Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolderIn = oFolder.Folders["RetrieveMail"];
```

I've also found a possible pitfall in your code:

```
Outlook.Items oItems = oFolderIn.Items;
            foreach (Outlook.MailItem oMailItem in oFolderIn.Items)
            {
                if (oMailItem.SenderName == "sender_name")
                {
```

Be aware, a folder may contain different kind of items. So, I'd suggest using object instead of mail item. Then you may check the item type and cast the object to the underlying type (mail, appointment and etc.).

Another point is that iterating over all items in a folder is not really a good idea. Use the `Find`/`FindNext` mehtods of the `Items` class instead. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Hello @Eugene Astafiev thank for the help, I already resolve my problem the inbound outlook email and save on SQL however I'm trying to create an email reply table that retrieve email reply data to SQL, Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest posting new question in new threads.